# How to find minimum set of combinations [python>itertools>product]: Code Review

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, iterator, memory-efficient

**How can I improve this code, without computing all possible combinations returned by itertools.product function.
Is there any other solutions to do it efficiently.**

This is what I have tried:

```
import itertools

mylist = [[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[1,2,3]]

k = [set(i) for i in list(itertools.product(*mylist))]
k = sorted(k)
D_all = list(k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(k))
D_all.sort(key=len)


# Finding and displaying the minimum order-split combination
l = len(D_all[0])
print("Minimum number of Distributor Combination found is: {}".format(l))
print("The Possible combinations of {} are: ".format(l))
D_best = []
c = 0
for n,i in enumerate(D_all):

    if len(i)<=l:
        c +=1
        print("{}:{}".format(c,i))
        D_best.append(i)
        if len(i)>l+1: break
```

> output:

```
Minimum number of Distributor Combination found is: 1
The Possible combinations of 1 are: 
1:{'1'}
2:{'3'}
```

Comment: This isn't really clear. If you only want the "singletons" (which I assume you mean length 1 sets) why to even bother with `.product`? You can simply take individual elements from the lists.

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @DeepSpace The way I understand it is that OP wants to get whatever `.product` gives him until all the singletons are `yield`ed and then stop.

Comment: ... But what is that? `[{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 4}, {3}]`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It is still not clear. Is the order of `.product`'s output even guaranteed/consistent? I'd assume it is not.

Comment: @DeepSpace it sure sounds like it is, in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). "The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product tuples are emitted in sorted order."

Comment: @DeepSpace I would assume it is, which would make this problem easier since you just have to know how many results you have to draw from it. If it is not you have to check for the singletons. Drawing **24** elements should cut it in this case.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis but how do you arrive at that number?

Comment: You mean, keep drawing sets until the length is 1?

Comment: And I have no idea what the for-loop with the `itertools.groupby` is suppose to be doing...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am working on the code, but the last singleton would be `{3}` given the list of lists and will be produced after 3 * 3 (all comb for 1) + 3 * 3 (all comb for 2) + 2 *3 (take a look at the position of 3 in the second list!)

Comment: It still isn't clear what this person wants.

Comment: So why not just use the union of the inputs as sets? That'd give you *all unique values you've input*.

Comment: Suppose we have output of product as : `[[1,2,3][1,2,4]]` instead computing the product which computes all 6 possible combinations, I want only `[1], [2]`, which is common between the two.

Comment: my intention is to reduce the computation time

Comment: @DeepSpace @ Martijn Pieters I have updated the question. Could you help to improve the code performance.

Comment: @shravan To be honest I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have it. You can take advantage of the fact that `itertools.product` `yields` its `tuple`s in a *deterministic* way; you know beforehand when all the *singletons* would be yielded. You just have to calculate when that will happen.

```
from itertools import islice, product
from functools import reduce

mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]

stop_cond = (len(mylist[0]) - 1) * reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) * len(y), mylist[1:])
pivot = mylist[0][-1]
stop_cond += reduce(lambda x, y: (x.index(pivot) + 1) * (y.index(pivot) + 1), mylist[1:])

k = [set(item) for item in islice(product(*mylist), stop_cond)]
print(k)  #[{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3}]
```

In this case, the last singleton would be `{3}` because `3` appears on the last position of the first `list` (i call that `pivot` in the code). To get its singleton you have to get all others first and that takes 3 * 3 yields for each. That is 9 + 9 = 18. Now for the last, you just need to find its index in the remaining lists (in a 1-index based system) and multiply those together.

Comment: Then use `islice()` instead of a `enumerate()` and a test each time to simply limit how many items are produced.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the feedback!